# ODI12C: Unable to Load Control Characters from XML File

Tags: xml, oracle-data-integrator, control-characters, invalid-characters

My XML File contains invalid Characters. Can some one help me how to load those from XML in ODI12C?

Error: ODI is throwing an error saying Invalid characters.

The value from the XML file looks like this : **LA CASUBADA FLINTRIDGE**.

But the original value is **LA CAÑADA FLINTRIDGE**

When I have searched I found that it is an control character and supported by oracle. But, I'm unable to load the value from the file.

Thanks for the help in advance.